# A login system with two access levels

Tags: c#

I am attempting to create a login system that has two access levels. If the access level is 1 they recieve the 'carer home page', if the level is 2 they recieve the 'administrator page'. The login form has a variable that validates the username and password against the credentials in the database, when the user clicks the button and the tryLogin variable is returns true the access level is taken from the database where the username in the database matches the username text field

Instead of loading any of the forms the message invalid login credentials shows. Ive spent a long time working on this and im lost, i hope this explains the problem enough.

```
public bool tryLogin(string uname, string pword)
        {
            MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host="";user="";password=""; database="";");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE username = '" + uname + "' AND password ='" + pword + "';");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();
            MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();



            if (reader.Read() != false)
            {
                if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == true)
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Connection.Close();
                    reader.Dispose();
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    return true;
                }
            }
            else
            {

                return false;

            }
        }



private void LoginBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            if (tryLogin(uname.Text, pword.Text) == true)
            {
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host="";user="";password=""; database="";");
                MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT access_level FROM Staff WHERE username = '" + uname + "';");

                cmd2.Connection = con;
                con.Open();


                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

                if (cmd2.Equals("1"))

                {
                    this.Hide();
                    CarerHomePage CarerHomePage = new CarerHomePage();
                    CarerHomePage.Show();
                }

                if (cmd2.Equals("2"))
                {
                    this.Hide();
                    AdministratorHome AdministratorHome = new AdministratorHome();
                    AdministratorHome.Show();

                }


                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login Credentials");
                }



            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Ahh my eyes! [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities galore. Haven't you heard of [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)?

Comment: "I've spent a long time working on this" tells me that you probably aren't using a debugger. Are you writing this without the aid of Visual Studio? If so, you might want to consider using [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/) until you feel more comfortable programming with C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot of room for improvement, but let's consider only what is eminently wrong.

The problem that's keeping you busy is that you are **comparing the result of the execution of the SQL command with the command itself**:

```
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
if (cmd2.Equals("1")) // What the fail?
```

I think you meant:

```
object accessCode = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();
if (accessCode != null && accessCode != DBNull.Value)
{
    if (accessCode.ToString() == "1")
    {
       this.Hide();
       CarerHomePage CarerHomePage = new CarerHomePage();
       CarerHomePage.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to read about SQL Injection.  Try adding the text

' OR 1 = 1 --

into your username textbox and trying to log in.  You should also consider reading about the built in asp.net user management/roles - it's the roles bit that would serve you well here.

Good link from ScottGu here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/18/427754.aspx

Comment: Excellent points but doesn't directly address the question so alas, no +1 here but a comment to say this is definitely important and necessary to consider. :)

Comment: @Chris - I would disagree - putting in an arbitrary 'two level login' system at the start is crippling the system for further expansion when someone asks for, e.g. a carer user that can access some admin functions.  Roles based authorisation is a much better way to go from the very start.

Comment: Definitely agree with Paddy here. Until you really know what you're doing, I think it's best to use a proven framework for security instead of scraping together your own.

Comment: @Joel: I'm never sure about point awarding. Is there any useful guideline on whether a good answer should answer the actual question or whether saying "you're asking the wrong question" is also a good answer? I was thinking of it in terms of the former whereas this answer is more the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Your Problem seems to be that you compare `cmd2` (an instance of `ExecuteReader`) to a `string`. Why should this ever be true? You should check the result of your query to the string instead of your query command.

Further your if-statement will show the Message box even if CarrerHomePage is loaded. You should try this way:

```
            if (cmd2.Equals("1"))
            {
                this.Hide();
                CarerHomePage CarerHomePage = new CarerHomePage();
                CarerHomePage.Show();
            }
            else if (cmd2.Equals("2"))
            {
                this.Hide();
                AdministratorHome AdministratorHome = new AdministratorHome();
                AdministratorHome.Show();

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login Credentials");
            }
```

Comment: Ah, beaten to it. Though you made some much better points than I was about to so you stopped me looking stupid too. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, there's a lot of issues here.  You should always use parameterized queries.

The problem is that you're using cmd.Equals instead of using the DataReader to retrieve the result row.

If you wanted to just retrieve a single value you could have used ExecuteScalar.  I suggest reading the Doc on MySqlCommand pretty thoroughly.

Finally, you can wrap your objects in using blocks... this will automatically close and dispose your options.  Shortens the code

```
public bool tryLogin(string uname, string pword)
{
    using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host="";user="";password=""; database="";"))
    using(MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE username = @name AND password = @pwd;"))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", uname);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pwd", pword);
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.Connection.Open();            
        using(var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            return reader.Read() && !reader.IsDBNull(0));                
        }
    }
}



private void LoginBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (tryLogin(uname.Text, pword.Text))
    {
        using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host="";user="";password=""; database="";"))
        using(MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT access_level FROM Staff WHERE username = '" + uname + "';"))
        {
            cmd2.Connection = con;
            cmd2.Connection.Open();                

            using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if(reader.Read())
                {
                    var accessLevel = reader.GetInt32("access_level");
                    switch(accessLevel)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            this.Hide();
                            CarerHomePage CarerHomePage = new CarerHomePage();
                            CarerHomePage.Show();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            this.Hide();
                            AdministratorHome AdministratorHome = new AdministratorHome();
                            AdministratorHome.Show();
                            break;
                        default:
                            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login Credentials");
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i can confirm the try login bool works correctly, if the credentials are wrong the 
message box displays. However if my credentials are correct, non of the forms will load no matter what I put in access_level. Its getting there slowly, im going through some tutorials on using the debugger as well seen as i am very new to this still.

private void LoginBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
        if (tryLogin(uname.Text, pword.Text) == true)
        {
            using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host="";user="";password=""; database="";"))
            using (MySqlCommand cmd2 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT access_level FROM Staff WHERE username = '" + uname + "';"))
            {

                cmd2.Connection = con;
                con.Open();


                object access_level = cmd2.ExecuteScalar();

                if (access_level != null && access_level != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    if (access_level.ToString() == "1")
                    {
                        this.Dispose();
                        CarerHomePage CarerHomePage = new CarerHomePage();
                        CarerHomePage.Show();
                    }


                    else if (access_level.ToString() == "2")
                    {
                        this.Dispose();
                        AdministratorHome AdministratorHome = new AdministratorHome();
                        AdministratorHome.Show();
                    }




                }

            }



        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login Credentials");
        }
}

}
```

}